# Calculate sum from two Tables for a specific User

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have an Table with Users and an Table with events that is related to the id from the Users Table. In each Event you can make points and i want to get the total points from an specific User.

It looks like this:

```
Users
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+

Events

+----------+---------+--------+
| event_id | user_id | points |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

// The event_id is related to an Event Table with specific data about the Event. but that not relevant.

The best could be to get the data from the user and the total points that he got in one query.

Thanks and Greetings,
Mottenmann

Comment: Maybe you could change your title to something like "calculate sum from two table for a specific user" or something like that. (Current title is misleading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*..to get the data from the user and the total points that he got in one query.*"

You need to join both tables first so you can manipulate the data. The query below uses `INNER JOIN` which only includes users on the result list if it has atleast one matching record on the `Events`. If you want to get all users even without a single matching record on the other table, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.username, SUM(b.points) totalPoints
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Events b
            ON a.ID = b.user_ID
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.username
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, an other question i got is if it is possbile to select all the totalPoints of each User and then get ordered by their value and then get the position of an specific User ?

Comment: @downvoter you have so many chances to downvote my answers. clearly `:)` happy downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

> "In each Event you can make points and i want to get the total points
>   from a specific User."

You could do something like this:

```
select sum(e.points) as points from users u
left join events e ON (u.id = e.user_id)
WHERE u.id = {$id}
```

where `{$id}` is the id of user.